# Wordpress Nginx Caching Recommendation 2016

Tags: nginx, cache

I have done a lot of research but haven't seen anywhere any concrete caching recommendation for my server configuration.

```
    DO single Droplet 2GB Ram
    Ubuntu 16
    Nginx 
    Php-fpm 7 
    Mysql 
    SSL
    must cache logged in users too
```

W3 total cache is not performing very well with this setup so I am thinking of abandoning it all together. That leaves me with no caching, no CDN at all at this point.

Any help pointing to the right direction with regards to my caching needs, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an extensive article on Nginx and Wordpress, with a particular focus on performance, caching, and CDNs. You can read the six part tutorial [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/).

SF likes a summary in the post in case websites disappear. It's difficult to summarize a tutorial that's dozens of pages long that took months to write, but here goes:

- If at all possible don't invoke PHP. Even invoking PHP is slow, execution is slow and uses a lot of RAM and CPU
- Use Nginx page caching where your website serves a significant number of anonymous users. If your content changes frequently you can use [microcaching](https://www.nginx.com/blog/benefits-of-microcaching-nginx/), if content is cached for even 1 second on busy sites it can reduce load significantly. Page caching can increase website performance by one or two orders of magnitude.
- Be careful not to cache pages for or from logged in users.
- Set your caching headers properly, and use a CDN like CloudFlare, along with CloudFlare PageRules to set up caching properly for different sections of your website. eg admin pages shouldn't be cached. You can even cache your pages on CloudFlare, though that means you don't have good web stats on your server - use Google Analytics or similar

**Update - sites with many logged in users**

You can't cache pages for logged in users as they're customised, so you need to push your caching back in the stack, primarily database and object caching. W3 total cache is useful, and you may want to integrate it with Redis/Memecached as the data store. Use a CDN to reduce server load and and latency, though serving static content from Nginx isn't going to take a server much.

Wordpress and PHP in general is pretty resource heavy, so you'll want to make sure you have sufficient resources - PHP requires both quite a bit of both RAM and CPU. Exactly how much depends on your load. Cloud providers help with this, as you can either scale up if you regularly need more resources, or you can use AWS or similar and scale out during periods of high load. This can significantly increase your system complexity, as you need shared directories for static content within Wordpress (images), load balancing, etc.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am running a membership site so I will need to cache logged in users... is that a big problem ?

Comment: It's a different use case with different considerations to mostly anonymous users. I've added a bit more text about that above.